# USB-IF Certified USB 3.x SuperSpeed External Self Powered 4+ Port Hub

Tags: usb, hub

I'm seeking a recommendation for a USB 3.x SuperSpeed hub with the following features:

- USB-IF USB 3.x SuperSpeed certified. If it's certified and it doesn't work well, it's probably no fault of the hub.
- Self-powered: I prefer self-powered hubs because they can source more current and seem to operate more reliably than those that are bus-powered.
- 4-12 ports. Fewer and the hub isn't very useful, more and the hub is too large.
- Under $200.

I'm struggling with finding a certified hub. I purchased an [AmazonBasics 10 Port USB 3.0 Hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GGYU8TC) and it works very poorly. Because it's not certified and I haven't purchased a second hub yet, I don't know if the issue is unique to the hub. Regardless, I would prefer a well tested hub that's gone through the trouble of [compliance testing](http://www.usb.org/developers/compliance/ssusb_testing/).

This [Belkin hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013P0JU66) says it's certified in the name but I don't see the SuperSpeed certified logo and it also seems to be unavailable on both Amazon and the Belkin website.